# XLRD - Extract Data from two columns into a dict with multiple values

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have an excel sheet with data that looks like this.

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
1       23      1
1       5       2
1       2       3
1       19      5
2       56      1
2       22      2
3       2       4
3       14      5
4       59      1
5       44      1
5       1       2
5       87      3
```

What I'd like to do is to extract Column1 and Column3 into a dictionary with keys that have multiple values.  Something like this:

```
1: 1,2,3,5
2: 1,2
3: 4,5
4: 1
5: 1,2,3
```

I'm new to Python, so any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

I can extract the data from the two columns and put it into a dict. But the multiple values per key I'm unsure about. And also unsure how to group all of the 1's, 2's, 3's from column1 into a single entry.

```
for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    results = dict((sheet.cell_value(rownum, 0), sheet.cell_value(rownum, 2)) for rownum in range(sheet.nrows))
return results
```

EDIT: Thanks to the help of this website, this is where I currently sit.

```
xl = pandas.read_excel(r"e:\py_projects\py_test\test_data.xlsx", sheetname='stockTestColumn1')
grouped = xl.groupby("columnid")
myData = grouped["volumeid"].apply(lambda x: [e for e in x])
```

What I'm now hoping to do is check for the presence of x for any given key.

So, if this is the output:

```
1: 1,2,3,4,5
2: 1,2
3: 4,5
4: 1
5: 1,2,3
```

I'm hoping to do something like:

```
check = myData.get('1')
if '4' in check:
    print "do something"
```

Comment: I can extract the data from the two columns and put it into a dict..  but the multiple values per key I'm unsure about.. and also unsure how to group all of the 1's, 2's, 3's from column1 into a single entry.

    for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    results = dict((sheet.cell_value(rownum, 0), sheet.cell_value(rownum, 2)) for rownum in range(sheet.nrows))
    return results

Answer (score 0):

this is a typical usecase of pandas [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html),

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

s = """Column1 Column2 Column3
1       23      1
1       5       2
1       2       3
1       19      5
2       56      1
2       22      2
3       2       4
3       14      5
4       59      1
5       44      1
5       1       2
5       87      3
"""

sio = StringIO(s)
df = pd.read_table(sio, sep=r"\s+")

grouped = df.groupby("Column1")
print grouped["Column3"].apply(lambda x: [e for e in x])
```

output:

```
1    [1, 2, 3, 5]
2          [1, 2]
3          [4, 5]
4             [1]
5       [1, 2, 3]
```

check the `sum` signature, `apply` actually passed in a iterator.
basically, pandas is the right tool to do such tabular data processing.

Comment: Thank you.  That is working!  I'm not entirely sure how it's working.. but I'm going to spend some time working on figuring it out.

Comment: yes, pandas is not that easy to pick up. but once you are there, you will enjoy the freedom it brings to you.